# Missing Table storage in Azure Portal

Tags: c#, azure, nlog, azure-table-storage

I am in the process of setting up a production release and hence creating all new services in the portal. I am battling to create a storage account that will allow me to create Azure tables. Currently I am using NLOG Azure Storage and it has always created tables when needed (If I delete them manually, re run my applications, it will re create).

If I manually try create the table I get an error (see code below)

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Configuration.AzureStorageConnectionString);
// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TestTable");
// Create the CloudTable if it does not exist
bool test = table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

I can create blobs easily but unable with tables. Our previous (staging) storage account was created on the old portal if that makes a difference?

Here is my config :

```xml
<add key="AzureStorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=productionhalostorage;AccountKey=abc;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" 
     xdt:Transform="Replace" 
     xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Ignore the xdt's I am using slow cheetah to maintain our configs.

Comment: can you share the error that you got ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the type of the storage account in question. It should be a `Standard` storage account and not `Blob Storage` account as `Blob Storage` accounts do not support tables.

If the type of the account is `Standard`, please check the redundancy type of that account. It should not be `ZRS` or `Premium LRS` as these redundancy type also do not support tables.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks so much!